# how to display data from PDO in foreach loop

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, stdclass

I'm new in php, I'm trying to display stdClass Object data via foreach loop inside table. But it's not working.

```
include("../config.php");
$get_data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `prd_rgistration`");
$prd_data = $get_data->fetchObject();
print_r($prd_data);
```

Data Print

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 24
    [password_db] => kignkgsnis
    [country_db] => United States
    [porder_db] => 56313241654321324
    [email_db] => nisa@gmail.com
)
```

Foreach Loop

```
foreach($prd_data as $eprd_data){
    echo $eprd_data->id;
}
```

it's giving this error

> Trying to get property of non-object

kindly tell me how i can display data. What thing i'm doing wrong.

Comment: you fetch only ONE Object. So you can't loop over it.

Comment: USe `$get_data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` then use foreach loop

Comment: oh i see now it's working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two way to do it:-

1.bit modification in your code:-

loop through the results of the query :-

```
while ($prd_data = $get_data->fetchObject()) {
    echo $prd_data->id;
}
```

2.Use `$prd_data = $get_data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` and then `foreach` as you used.

```
foreach($prd_data as $eprd_data){
    echo $eprd_data->id;
}
```

Note:- According to me you are interested in fetching all the records,So go for the second one.Thanks

***One other way is also suggested by @Your common Sense***

Answer (score 3):

You're only getting one object, not an array, so wrap the while loop around fetch

```
while ($prd_data = $get_data->fetchObject())
  echo $prd_data->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add this line in your `config.php`

   ```
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   ```
2. Change your code to

   ```
   $get_data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `prd_rgistration`");
   foreach($get_data as $prd_data){
       echo $prd_data->id;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the results of the query :

```
while ($prd_data = $get_data->fetchObject()) {
    echo $prd_data->id;
}
```

Instead of

```
$prd_data = $get_data->fetchObject();
```

Comment: Typo: `$eprd_data` doesn't exist now